# Pointer object calling a constructor gives some other not expected result

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Test 
{
    public:
  int x;
  
  Test() { x = 5;}
};
 
int main()
{
   Test *t;

   cout << t->x;

}
```

It should print "5" but instead, it prints "1528349827".
Test *t should initialize x by 5. and t->x should print 5. But it gives the above number. Can someone please explaint to me what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Test *t;` should initialize x by 5.

That's false. This line of code just declares a pointer to a `Test`. There is no `Test` object, and so no constructor is run that initializes any `x` to 5.

Doing `t->x` is undefined behavior, because there is no object to dereference. The program could do anything, including printing out a garbage value.

To actually point `t` to a `Test` object, you need to allocate memory, or point to an existing `Test` object:

```
Test *t = new Test{};
// or
Test a;
Test *t = &a;
```

and now doing `t->x` is guaranteed to give the value 5.